# Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, character-encoding

I am getting the following error message :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL: select * from `tblleaddocs` where (`docname` = Discover_Online_Savingś.pdf and `leadId` = 0) limit 1)
```

Noteice the where condition : the doc name is `Discover_Online_Savingś.pdf` and it have `ś`.
I know that its collations related issue

I have tried the changing the table charset and collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` but still its not working for me and getting the same issue.

The actual laravel query from which i am getting that error :

`DB::table('tableName')->where('docname', $originalfile)->first();`

Comment: Have you had a look at the related questions to the side(and down a bit) of this page?

Comment: That query look like you are missing single quotes around s text column here `\`docname\` = 'Discover_Online_Savingś.pdf'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly The query works just fine for other records not having `ś`.

Comment: `ś` exists in utf8 and in latin7, but not latin1.  Not a very common letter; I have not found out what language(s) it is used in.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.